# Using image causes strange white frame around

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Im trying to create a button in C# with the image as the button, I don't really want to use a picture box as i Require the "Label" bit of the button as the text for the buttons aren't in the image, This is what it looks like

[image: Play button image]

If anyone can help me fix that white frame it would be much appreciated, Thanks!

EDIT: I found what was causing it but still no fix :( The BackColor on the actual form is where the white is coming from but you can't set the BackColor of a form to Transparent :/

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: hard to say from here but it looks like you have a white frame rond your button, as opposed to a transparent one. We need the code if that isn't enough of a clue

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WinForms -  custom button unwanted border when form unselected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399215/c-sharp-winforms-custom-button-unwanted-border-when-form-unselected)

Comment: Not much more we can do without knowing WinForm/Metro/etc. or some kind of code snippet.

Comment: It is WinForm and what sort of code do you need? the only code i can think of is the `play.BackgroundImage = vars.buttons;` and vars.buttons is `public Image button = Image.FromFile(path + @"\Data\img\button_normal.png");`

Answer (score 0):

I think a `Background.Color = Transparent` should fix it if WinForms.

**Update**
If you have set border and background properties to transparent, double check the white border to be transparent in the actual graphic?

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. In the button properties every color i can find is set to Transparent.It is WinForms and im setting the image via `play.BackgroundImage = vars.buttons;`

Answer (score 0):

Your image must have transparent background. Also see @IAbstract's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399215/c-sharp-winforms-custom-button-unwanted-border-when-form-unselected/9400099#9400099) to remove the border you should set the `FlatAppearance.BorderColor` to transparent. The whole code to remove completely the border looks like:

```
customButton.TabStop = false;
//it's the best thing set flatstyle to flat when dealing with a custom button
customButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; 
customButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
//set the border color to transparent by setting the alpha to 0 (it doesn't support Color.Transparent)
customButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This did not work either :/ but thanks anyway EDIT: I had already read the Question but after no luck decided to ask one myself :(

Comment: Are you sure the background image is transparent?

Comment: Yup, I have gone through the Form, The Buttons, The Picture box, Everything :( I made the Buttons myself in Photoshop so the image itself is transparent