# How to remove white space between border and BackColor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if there is a neat workaround with these white lines (white space) between border and BackColor?

[image: screenshot]

I have never really put much attention to these things before, but now it is starting to annoy me. Is there an easy way to remove this white space? Is this a bug?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400099/1160796

Comment: As @basher stated change the style to FlatStyle. That should work.

Comment: Tried to do that to, but TextBox doesn't have FlatStyle property. Maybe I have mislead you. This is TextBox on picture not Button.

Comment: @user1485251 yea my fault. I just thought it was similar and might lead you in the right direction. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into properties. BorderStyle -> FixedSingle

Comment: Haha, I didn't expect that. Thanks it worked. Border is a bit different, but nonetheless. Thanks again :)