# C# winform button inside border after click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been spending over 2 hours to try fix this but I can't, really angry and stress with this.

[image]

You can easily seen the black border insde Sign in button, it's show when I click.

I have googled plenty of times but I can't fix that.

Some one told me do that, not working.

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public override void NotifyDefault(bool value)
    {
        base.NotifyDefault(false);
    }
}
```

I've done this too but get nothing: [C# WinForms -  custom button unwanted border when form unselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399215/c-sharp-winforms-custom-button-unwanted-border-when-form-unselected)

Comment: Paste your code please If you made a custom button.

Comment: No, I use original button

Comment: And you didn't paint it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I use original button because while I paint it myself, I do not know what type of border I need to set is `0`

Comment: So you do paint it yourself? If so, it would help if you'd show us your `OnPaint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solutions, this really simple and this answer for who have similar question.

Problem is button focus, to handle this, simplest way is

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Select();
}
```

Thanks everybody for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

That rectangle indicates that your `Button` has focus. It doesn't make too much sense to hide it; however, it is possible to do so:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: My buttom is not custom button, how can I add this code?