# How to delete button border after clicking outside of Form C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapp

I made a simple button, but when i click outside of win form my button getting a black border. By the way i set `BorderSize` to "0" and it works great while i clicking inside of my form.

```
this.button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

That's how it looks like.

[image: example]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c) and check if it could solve your problem

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400099/5734097) solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround is to set the [FlatAppearance.BorderColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance.bordercolor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_FlatButtonAppearance_BorderColor) of the Button to its `Parent.BackColor`:

```
this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = this.button1.Parent.BackColor;
```

You could set this Property subscribing to the [ParentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ParentChanged);k(System.Windows.Forms.Button);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.Button);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event (or overriding [OnParentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onparentchanged?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), if it's a Custom Control) if the Control can be assigned to another parent at some point.

You can also perform the same operation in batch, using the [HandleCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.HandleCreated);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) event and have all the Buttons (with **`FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat`**) subscribe to the event in the Form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(btn => btn.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Flat))
    {
        button.HandleCreated += (s, e) => { 
            button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = button.Parent.BackColor; 
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems a focus problem. Try to reset the focus when the cursor leave the control.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code to your forms load event.

```
 btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;//You can also use the popup flat style
 btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = btn.Parent.BackColor;
 btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```